# Laravel ckeditor toolbar is not styled properly it is showing without styles

Tags: jquery, laravel, ckeditor

I have use the Ckeditore in laravel and its functionality is working fine but toolbar styles are not working.
This is the code of ckeditore.

```
      <textarea name="other_detail" id="other_detail" 
         class="form-control input-field" >
            <?php echo @$project[0]->other_detail;?>
            </textarea>

  <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
 CKEDITOR.replace('other_detail');
 </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code HTML and CKEditor initialization code

Comment: Take a look to the Network tab of your browser to see if there's no error in loading stylesheets.

Comment: Tried all that noting in network tab or console.

Comment: Show your console screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Please share your layout. so I can see how you are using the js and CSS files in the layout.
I am sure this issue is due to some of your CSS.